# How to remove item from NSArray depending on the items contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I am creating an NSArray of NSStrings, however one of the arrays that is entered is a set of quotation marks:

```
""
```

I would like to know hot to exclude these from my array, I have tried using a predicate but it's not working.

This is what my code looks like:

```
NSString *tempSymbolsString = [tempAxesDictionary objectForKey:@"Symbols"];
        NSArray *tempSymbolsArray = [tempSymbolsString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
        tempSymbolsArray = [symbolsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != """""]];
        NSLog(@"%@", tempSymbolsArray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually is even simpler than this. Since you only got strings in your array, create a mutable copy and remove all occurrences of `""`. Something like this perhaps:

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [tempSymbolsArray mutableCopy];
[temp removeObject:@"\"\""];
```

This works since `removeObject:` will compare objects via `isEqual:` and remove any matches.

Comment: Duh! This is easier than my approach of iterating through the array. Good call.

Comment: okay, so maybe I am wrong. for some reason this is what my array looks like. 1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    ""
and I think that the "" is making my for loop run one to many times. but the code you gave me did not remove the ""

Comment: okay this works. i found out the commaseperatedbystring has a ;  at the end.. so then its adding nothing into the array so i just added -1 to my count.

Comment: @HurkNburkS It sounds like you have an empty string, not a quoted empty string. Change the code to `[temp removeObject:@""];`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it yourself:

```
NSString *tempSymbolsString = tempAxesDictionary[@"Symbols"];
NSMutableArray *symbolsArray = [[tempSymbolsString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] mutableCopy];
for (NSUInteger i = symbolsArray.count; i > 0; i--) {
    if ([symbolsArray[i - 1] isEqualToString:@"\"\""]) {
        [symbolsArray removeObjectAtIndex:i - 1];
    }
}
```

At the end the `symbolsArray` will have all values except those matching `""`.

BTW - your original predicate probably needs a bunch of escaping:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != \"\\\"\\\"\""]
```